# Add dynamic header to request-promise options (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having trouble adding a header to a request-promise (npm) request using a variable (headersTest). If I hard-code the value in options, I receive the expected API response. If I create the header in a variable and add that to options, the API rejects the request (the header key is not recognised). When I log the headersTest variable it would appear identical to the hard-coded value, but doesn't work.

Here is the relevant code section:

```
const headersTest = "'x-custom-date':'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 09:45:18 EST'";
console.log(headersTest);

    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        uri: 'http://' + whatEvz,
        qs: {
            queryString
        },
        headers: {
            //'x-custom-date':'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 09:45:18 EST'
            headersTest
        },
        json: true
    };

    rp(options)
        .then(function(results){
            res.send(results);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.send("Shite! That didn't work! " + err.message);
        });
```

It seems I'm missing something in my understanding as to how variables are interpreted within options. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: you'll want `headers: { 'x-custom-date':'Fri, 27 Oct 2017 09:45:18 EST' }`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX, you are correct but I couldn't work out how to get this into the options object dynamically. I have now figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using object properties, rather than trying to pass on object into options.headers. I actually had an array of headers and used lodash to add the headers like so:

```
 _.each(myHeaders, function (val, key) {
            _.each(val, function (val, key) {
                options.headers[key] = val;
            });
        })
```